# Configure SSO for Azure AD and GSuite users in .NET

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-authentication, azure-ad-b2b

I am developing a web application with .NET 5 and I would like to add SSO to the application with both Azure AD (organizational Microsoft accounts) and G-Suite accounts. When the user enters the web application he should be given the option to sign it either with their Microsoft organizational account or their G-Suite account. The application is to be hosted on Azure as an app service. Furthermore, I also have Azure Active Directory setup for my organization so I can create app registrations.

The issue that I have is a lack of understanding on what to use to achieve this kind of authentication in my web application.

Azure Active Directory provides both the B2C and the B2B options to configure authentication. Azure AD B2B seems to be more intended to give suppliers/partners access to apps and resources in Azure and can be achieved by adding users as guests in the main organization's AD.
On the other hand Azure AD B2C appears to be more customer focused where users can sign in with their social accounts but also work accounts. I accessed the Woodgrove demo solution that is listed on the Microsoft Docs (https://woodgrovedemo.com/Account/LogIn) and tried to sign in with a work account where the work account was a G-Suite account. However, the work account had to be a "Microsoft account" so I couldn't sign it. I also tried the sign in with a personal account option but this time it did not let me sign in with my organization's Microsoft account.

There are also articles about configuring authentication in .NET that do not even mention Azure AD B2B and B2C like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp?view=aspnetcore-5.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0 . In these articles, it shows how to configure Azure AD and Gmail authentication separately and there doesn't seem to be an option to configure both at once. Also, for Gmail there is no restriction to allow G-Suite accounts only.

How can I configure SSO authentication in my .NET 5 web app with both Azure AD accounts (Microsoft organizational accounts / Office 365 accounts - not sure which term is correct) and G-Suite accounts? Do I need to use Azure AD B2B or Azure B2C to achieve this or I don't even need these?

I would appreciate any kind of help or advice for this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want self service sign up to your app with those types of accounts? Will your app offer any O365 API functionality or is it all your own custom services/APIs?

Comment: Self-service sign up should be allowed. The flow would be that an admin of the application subscription (in-app subscription to be clear) will give access rights to a user to access that app subscription. So the user, would need to sign up in the application to access their subscription. O365 functionality, no, it will all be custom services and APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The type of users in the application will drive what you are going to use:

**Customer** - use an Azure Ad B2C tenant
**Partner** - use an Azure AD B2b tenant
**Employee** - use your organization Azure AD tenant(used by Azure and Ofice365 as well)

Note that there is nothing preventing you from using multiply Idp in your asp.net core application, Just have to make multiply app registrations and chain them together like so:

services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(...).AddGoogleAccount(...)

Azure app service presents a special case where it comes with a build in EasyAuth module. It will do app registration for you, and also you are able to chain multiple Idps there, (e.g. you can pick both AAD and google), and doing all those without any code or configuration change.

The two settings in Azure app service blade are
**Authentication (Classic)** - if you only want to do authentication.
**Authentication** - if you want to do google API call as well.

So be sure to check it out first.

Comment: Thanks. The chaining of multiple IDPs looks like an interesting that I can test. I need to see what happens when the user tries to access an authorized method with this approach, will they be redirected to a login where they can choose either Microsoft or Google, or does it pick one at random. Also, for the "AddMicrosoftAccount" I believe that is only for person accounts and wouldn't work for organizational accounts, so I need to find a different IDP I guess. The Easy Auth module, can add complexities while in development I think, as it will only work when the app is published.

Comment: Hi I give a thought based on comments. It is best to use an Azure Ad B2c tenant to implement this just because it can incorporate both an Azure AD and Google account. Also the link for asp.net core authentication is a bit outdated. The newer version it is using System.Identity.Web, and I included a link for B2C implementation here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C

Comment: I agree easyauth is not useful those days, as the correct implementation is simple and included in any quick start VS templates